# Defining an object as an operation on two other objects in Scala

Tags: scala

I am implementing sign analysis in Scala for a lab at the university.
To do this, I need an arithmetic on abstract values like `Pos`, `Neg`, `Zero`,
`NonPos`, `NonNeg`, ... So I have to declare methods `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` etc... on
those abstract values. I actually do not need to define everything
pair-wise, but can define a 'core' of operations on `Pos`, `Neg`, and `Zero`,
and then use upper bounds to define, for example:

```
NonPos + Pos = leastUpperBound(Zero + Pos, Neg + Pos)
```

where for instance `leastUpperBound(Zero, Neg) = NonPos`

In Scala, I use case objects to represent the values, and have a
`leastUpperBound()` method on every one of them. But I still have some code
duplication I don't manage to get rid of, for instance I define:

```
case object NonNeg extends Sign {
    def +(other: Sign) = leastUpperBound(Zero + other, Pos + other)
    def -(other: Sign) = ...
    def * = ...
    ...
}
```

and the I must do the same thing for:

```
case object NonPos extends Sign {
    def +(other: Sign) = leastUpperBound(Zero + other, Neg + other)
    ...
}
```

and again:

```
case object NonZero extends Sign {
    def +(other: Sign) = leastUpperBound(Neg + other, Neg + other)
    ...
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to have some kind of "type factory" so that I could
say something in the spirit of:

```
case object NonNeg extends UpperBoundSign[Pos, Zero]
```

My intuition is that it won't be possible with `Pos` and `Zero` being `object`s,
but I'm not that familiar with Scala so I may forget some feature or pattern that would
allow me to do that.

Does anyone have any idea for removing this duplication ?
Could maybe Scala macros in 2.10 be a good fit for this problem ?

I hope the question is clear,
thank you.

EDIT: thanks to @cmbaxter's answer and some refactoring on my part, I came up with a solution I like. If someone is interested in seeing it, it can be found there: https://gist.github.com/Ricordel/5553405.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be confusing type identifiers and instances of classes.  I believe that in order to get the functionality you want, you would need to define `UpperBoundSign` as an abstract class taking two constructor args as opposed to a generic type with two type identifier slots.  Here is an oversimplified solution option that could work for what you want to do.  I apologize if this is completely not what you wanted:

```
trait Sign{
  def +(other: Sign):Sign
}

abstract class UpperBoundSign(pos:Sign, neg:Sign) extends Sign{
  def leastUpperBound(pos:Sign, neg:Sign):Sign
  def +(other: Sign) = leastUpperBound(pos + other,  neg + other)
}

case object Pos extends Sign{
  def +(other:Sign) = ...
}

case object Neg extends Sign{
  def +(other:Sign) = ...
}

case object NonNeg extends UpperBoundSign(Pos, Neg){
  def leastUpperBound(pos:Sign, neg:Sign) = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know we could inherit that way, I'll go to bed less ignorant tonight. I think this will do perfectly, I'll even be able to have a `List[Sign]` as argument to `UpperBoundSign` to upper-bound an arbitraty amount of types.

Answer (score 1):

ok, sorry I misundertood your question
Anyway, I tried out your code and it looks quite interesting, but since I like simplicity I tried to come up with a simpler solution to your problem.

```
object Sign {
  case object Pos extends Sign
  case object Neg extends Sign
  case object Zero extends Sign
  case object Undefined extends Sign
  case object NonPos extends SignSet(Set(Neg, Zero)) {
    override def toString = "NonPos"
  }
  case object NonNeg extends SignSet(Set(Pos, Zero)) {
    override def toString = "NonNeg"
  }
  case object NonZero extends SignSet(Set(Pos, Neg)) {
    override def toString = "NonZero"
  }
  case object AnySign extends SignSet(Set(Pos, Neg, Zero)) {
    override def toString = "AnySign"
  }

  private val signs = List(Pos, Neg, Zero, Undefined, NonPos, NonNeg, NonZero, AnySign)

  private def calc(op: Symbol, s1: Sign, s2: Sign): Sign = {
    val sign = _calc(op, s1, s2)
    signs.find(_ == sign).getOrElse(sign)
  }

  private def _calc(op: Symbol, s1: Sign, s2: Sign): Sign = (op, s1, s2) match {
    case (op, set: SignSet, sign) => set.flatMap(s => _calc(op, s, sign))
    case (op, sign, set: SignSet) => set.flatMap(s => _calc(op, sign, s))
    case (_, Undefined, _) => Undefined
    case (_, _, Undefined) => Undefined

    case ('+, x, y) if x == y => x
    case ('+, x, Zero) => x
    case ('+, Zero, x) => x
    case ('+, Pos, Neg) => SignSet(Pos, Neg, Zero)
    case ('+, Neg, Pos) => SignSet(Pos, Neg, Zero)

    case ('-, x, Neg) => _calc('+, x, Pos)
    case ('-, x, Pos) => _calc('+, x, Neg)
    case ('-, x, Zero) => x

    case ('*, Zero, _) => Zero
    case ('*, Pos, x) => x
    case ('*, Neg, Pos) => Neg
    case ('*, Neg, Neg) => Pos
    case ('*, Neg, Zero) => Zero

    case ('/, _, Zero) => Undefined
    case ('/, x, y) => _calc('*, x, y)
  }
}

sealed trait Sign {
  import Sign.calc
  def +(other: Sign) = calc('+, this, other)
  def -(other: Sign) = calc('-, this, other)
  def *(other: Sign) = calc('*, this, other)
  def /(other: Sign) = calc('/, this, other)
  def flatten: Sign = this
  def |(other: Sign): Sign = other match {
    case sign if sign == this => this
    case SignSet(signs) => SignSet(signs + this)
    case sign => SignSet(this, sign)
  }
}

object SignSet {
  def apply(signs: Set[Sign]) = new SignSet(signs)
  def apply(signs: Sign*) = new SignSet(signs.toSet)
  def unapply(set: SignSet) = Some(set.signs)
}
class SignSet(val signs: Set[Sign]) extends Sign {
  def flatMap(f: Sign => Sign) = SignSet(signs.map(f)).flatten
  override def flatten = signs.map(_.flatten).reduce(_ | _)
  override def |(other: Sign) = other match {
    case SignSet(otherSigns) => SignSet(otherSigns | signs)
    case sign => SignSet(signs + sign)
  }
  override def toString = signs.mkString("SignSet(", ", ", ")")
  def equals(other: SignSet) = signs == other.signs
  override def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case set: SignSet => equals(set)
    case _ => false
  }
}

import Sign._

println(Pos / NonPos)
println(Pos + Neg)
println(NonZero * Zero)
println(NonZero / NonPos)
println(NonZero - NonZero)
println(NonZero + Zero)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed simpler and much shorter. Actually the greatest benefit is probably that it has a better precision when joining a `Pos` with an `Undefined` for instance, my previously posted solution will lose precision (saying it can be anything) while yours won't. Moreover this reminded me of the existence of Symbol in Scala, thanks for taking the time to post this!

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with set theory.

```
abstract class Sign(name: String) {
  def contains(sign: Sign) = sign eq this
  def +(other: Sign) = findSign(Union(this, other))
  def -(other: Sign) = findSign(Difference(this, other))

  def equals(other: Sign) = (contains(Pos), contains(Neg), contains(Zero)) == (other.contains(Pos), other.contains(Neg), other.contains(Zero))
  override def equals(other: Any) = {
    if(other.isInstanceOf[Sign]) equals(other.asInstanceOf[Sign])
    else false
  }
  override def toString = name
}

case class Union(sign1: Sign, sign2: Sign, name: String = "Union") extends Sign(name) {
  override def contains(sign: Sign) = sign1.contains(sign) || sign2.contains(sign)
}
case class Intersection(sign1: Sign, sign2: Sign, name: String = "Intersection") extends Sign(name) {
  override def contains(sign: Sign) = (sign1.contains(sign) || sign2.contains(sign)) && !(sign1.contains(sign) && sign2.contains(sign))
}
case class Difference(sign1: Sign, sign2: Sign, name: String = "Difference") extends Sign(name) {
  override def contains(sign: Sign) = sign1.contains(sign) && !sign2.contains(sign)
}
case class Negation(sign: Sign, name: String = "Negation") extends Sign(name) {
  override def contains(s: Sign) = !sign.contains(s)
}

case object Zero extends Sign("Zero")
case object Pos extends Sign("Pos")
case object Neg extends Sign("Neg")
val NonPos = Negation(Pos, "NonPos")
val NonNeg = Negation(Neg, "NonNeg")
val NonZero = Negation(Zero, "NonZero")
val AnySign = Union(NonZero, Zero, "AnySign")
val NoSign = Negation(AnySign, "NoSign")

val signs = List(Zero, Pos, Neg, NonPos, NonNeg, NonZero, AnySign, NoSign)
def findSign(sign: Sign) = signs.find(_ == sign).get

println(Pos + Neg)
println(NonNeg - Zero)
println(NonZero + Zero)
println(Pos + Neg + Zero)
println(NonPos - Neg - Zero)
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wasn't very clear on the underlying problem, but what I want to do is give the sign of the result of an operation given the signs of the operands, in a safe way. For instance, `NonZero + Zero = NonZero` as adding 0 to a non-null number cannot make it null. So it's not what you suggest, but thanks for taking a try ! If you're interested, I'll post a gist of what I came up with in the main question.